# Select query eliminating unwanted rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and I am having trouble finding the solution.

I have TABLE1 with columns `col1` and `col2`

```
col1    col2
-------------
a       no
a       no
a       yes
b       no
c       yes
c       no 
d       yes
```

I want no repetitions from col1 but prioritize col2 when having "yes"

I want something like this

```
col1    col2
-------------
a       yes
b       no
c       yes
d       yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

#### Approach 1

You may use `row_number` to retrieve a row number ordered by `col2` in descending order  that may be used to filter your results eg.

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY col1
            ORDER BY col2 DESC
        ) rn
    FROM
        my_table
) t
WHERE rn=1;
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | yes |
| b | no |
| c | yes |
| d | yes |

#### Approach 2

or simply use a group by `col1` with the `MAX` function. The group by will ensure that for each `col1` value you will receive the `MAX` of `col2` that is `yes` if available and `no` if not.

```
SELECT
     col1,
     MAX(col2) as col2
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    col1;
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | yes |
| b | no |
| c | yes |
| d | yes |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQtCNKw7GNvjUjXcaBCtRK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You will first want to do a distinct select on column one. Then you will want to make a case statement which is essentially a if statement in other languages. The case needs to be if column 1 is yes return it. if it is not yes then return no. It would look something like this

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

Comment: a select distinct with a case statement would return each unique pairing of col1 and the conditional on col2, which would not meet the askers request.

Answer (score 0):

ggordon's answer will work well enough, but just since a window function isn't strictly necessary I figured I'd pass another solution:

```
select distinct 
a.col1,
ifnull(b.col2, 'no') col2

from my_table a
left join (
    select distinct
    col1,
    col2
    from my_table

    where col2 = 'yes'
  ) b on a.col1 = b.col1
```

Output:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| a    | yes  |
| b    | no   |
| c    | yes  |
| d    | yes  |
```